# I seem to have lost my apt-key after a reinstall

Tags: apt, updates

I keep getting this message when running an update:

```
The repository '[http://ppa.launchpad.net/landscape/19.10/ubuntu  Release][1]' does not have a Release file
Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you are using?

Comment: 19.10 has gone end of life. Please remove any reference in your system and replace it by a current version

Comment: I'm using 20.04, so yes I've had to carefully track down any reference of that particular repo, and manually replace it. Problem is solved now with a little more understanding of apt-key and versions.